# Getting the client locale in a jersey request

Tags: java, jersey, locale, jax-rs

What is the best and more portable way to get the **client locale** in the context of a Jersey (JAX-RS) request? I have the following code:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
@Path("/myrequest")
public Response myRequest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Locale locale = ...
}
```

Please assume that the "request" is made by some javascript code within a browser, by calling `window.location = ...;`

Comment: can you describe more about the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Locale locale = request.getLocale();`

Answer (score 3):

Use the HTTP Header for that. To request the numeric value in the US Locale decimal you can request like that:

`GET /metrics/007/size 
Accept-Language: en-US`

Then from the code:

```
public Response myRequest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
Locale locale = request.getLocale();
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The client should set the [`Accept-Language` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14).

Comment: That's assumed to be true. In fact my question was a bit bogus, the answer is straight-forward: given the `HttpServletRequest` it's just a matter of calling `getLocale()`...

Answer (score 2):

Getting language/locale data can be done in different ways depending on the final objective. According to the question, I believe the most suitable solution is:

```
@GET
public Response myRequest( @Context HttpServletRequest request )
{
   Locale locale = request.getLocale();
   ...
}
```

Another potential alternative is using a language query parameter:

```
@GET
public Response myRequest( @QueryParam( "language" ) String language )
{
   ...
}
```

Or alternatively, the "Accept-Language" header parameter:

```
@GET
public Response myRequest( @HeaderParam( "Accept-Language" ) String acceptLanguage )
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As user3774109 answered, use the `Accept-Language` HTTP Header. Although it is used in the Jersey implementation, the interface `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` is not actually part of the JAX-RS API. A cleaner way to get the preferred accepted language would be:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
@Path("/myrequest")
public Response myRequest(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    Locale locale = headers.getAcceptableLanguages().get(0);
    ...
}
```